# Solving $\lfloor \sqrt{9n^2+1}\rfloor+\lfloor\sqrt{9n^2+2}\rfloor+...+\lfloor\sqrt{9n^2+24n}\rfloor=349 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Solve over positive integers:
>
> $$\lfloor \sqrt{9n^2+1}\rfloor+\lfloor\sqrt{9n^2+2}\rfloor+...+\lfloor\sqrt{9n^2+24n}\rfloor=349 $$

I started with $x-1<\lfloor x\rfloor \le x$:

$$\lfloor \sqrt{9n^2+1}\rfloor > \sqrt{9n^2+1}-1 > 3n-1$$

Using this for each term and adding: $349 > 24n(3n-1)$. This is true for $n=2$, but not for $n=3$. So $n\le 2$. Also $\sqrt{9n^2+24n} < \sqrt{9n^2+24n+16}=3n+4$. So

$$\lfloor \sqrt{9n^2+24n}\rfloor< \sqrt{9n^2+24n} < 3n+4$$

Using this for each term and adding: $349 < 24n(3n+4)$. This is true for $n=2$, but not for $n=1$. So $n\ge 2$. Combining $n=2$. Is this reasoning correct? Can this equation be solved in a easier way?

Comment: You still have to show that it *is* a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by noting that there are $24n$ terms, each of which is at least $3n$.  We need $72n^2\lt 349$ so $n$ can only be $1$ or $2$.  If $n=2$ there are $48$ terms with the range being from $\lfloor \sqrt {37}\rfloor =6$ to $\lfloor \sqrt {84}\rfloor =9$ which is clearly in the ballpark.  If $n=1$ there are $24$ terms and the largest is $\lfloor \sqrt {33}\rfloor =5$, which is too small, so the only solution can be $n=2$.

Finally we note that for $n=2$ there are $12$ terms with a floor of $6,\ 15$ with a floor of $7,\ 17$ with a floor of $8,\ $ and $4$ with a floor of $9$.  Indeed
$$12\cdot 6+15\cdot 7+17\cdot 8+4\cdot 9=349$$

Answer (score 1):

In short:

$$\lfloor \sqrt{9n^2+k} \rfloor = \begin{cases}
3n, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1\leq k \leq 6n\\
3n+1,\ \ \ \ \ 6n+1\leq k\leq 12n+3\\
3n+2,\ \ \ \ \ 12n+4\leq k \leq 18n+8\\
3n+3,\ \ \ \ \ 18n+9 \leq 24n
\end{cases}$$

With this, the equation boils down to:

$$3n\cdot 6n+(3n+1)(6n+3)+(3n+2)(6n+5)+(3n+3)(6n-8)=349$$

or $72n^2+36n-360=0$, a second degree equation.